# What are Rextro high scores?

Tags: yooka-laylee

If you beat his score, you get a prize, probably a pagie. But what are his high scores?

I guess he has an arcade game in every world, so what are his 5 scores?

Comment: FYI from what I've found there appears to be 8 machines, not 5

Comment: There's only 5 tokens so there must be 5? Where to you take that it could be 8?

Comment: No idea, I have the game but haven't touched it yet.  There's a wiki for the game already, and the [Arcade Machine page](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Arcade_Machines) states that there are 8.  Maybe 3 of them don't have Rextro scores?  The [Play Coin page](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Play_Coin) also says there are 8.

Comment: Maybe the multiplayer mode has 3 more games that don't appear in the main game.

Comment: Rextro's arcade in Hivory Towers has 3 additional games (besides the 5 also found in each worlds). You don't need a coin to play them, and they don't seem to unlock anything when you beat his score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of all high scores to beat on each of the 5 worlds, with link to source. Below in the comments, Fredy31 noticed that you always have to play the game again to get the second pagie, even if you beat the high score on your first game.

- [World 1 (Tribalstack Tropics)](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-04-10-yooka-laylee-guide-and-walkthrough-tips-for-completing-and-finding-every-collectible-4686?page=2)

> this time beat the high score of 2 minutes 30 seconds

- [World 2 (Glittergaze Glacier)](http://www.ign.com/wikis/yooka-laylee/Glitterglaze_Glacier_Pagies)

> Then, attempt to beat Rextro’s high score to get another Pagie. Score
>   higher than 1400 points to do so.

- [World 3 (Moodymaze Marsh)](http://tankwarroom.com/article/716/yooka-laylee-all-pagies-in-moodymaze-marsh-world-3)

> Play Rextro’s game again and beat the high score of 4000

- [World 4 (Capital Cashino)](http://tankwarroom.com/article/717/yooka-laylee-all-pagies-in-capital-cashino-world-4)

> Another Pagie can be earned by playing Rextro’s arcade machine again
>   and beating the high score of 24,000.

- [World 5 (Galleon Galaxy)](http://tankwarroom.com/article/718/yooka-laylee-all-pagies-in-galleon-galaxy-world-5)

> Play Rextro’s arcade again and beat the high score of 14,000

Comment: Noticed, with the last text, that you always have to play the game again to get the second pagie. Was confused because when I played the 1st world game I got a better score than what was answered.